# Prevent iframe from opening in a new window

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I have seen some answers about it but i have a same issue that is rather a little more complex.

I have a site about tourism build in wordpress localy and i have integrated in it some iframes from booking.com

The iframes are working good but when you click on the links inside it opens on a new window. All i want is to reload inside the iframe.

Also if some have worked with booking.com before i would like to ask...when you search from there search box and hit search is there a way not to open in a new window but instead in a new page inside the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, due to [cross-domain policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions, you simply cannot control any of the booking.com iframe. That's by design, for security reasons. Unless you deal with a same-origin iframe (i.e. from the same domain name) there is nothing you can do here. You depend on booking.com's implementation entirely.

You may want to consider a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/booking-search-hotel/ (found from a quick search) or see if other XML API solutions are available for more control.